# How to update this Select Query to Update? - So far, it just hangs

Tags: sql, magento, select, sql-update, magento2

I eventually managed to get what I was after by grouping and then applying an additional filter with 'HAVING' which is probably not the best way to go about it, but I am new to SQL and this is the only way I could achieve what I was after... which was a list of 'simple' items where the 'qty' is 0 and the range status (attribute_id = 168) is Discontinued (ID 96) and the 'status' (attribute_id = 97) is enabled (id = 1).  This is shown below:

```
SELECT
  `mgic_catalog_product_entity`.`sku` AS `sku`,
  `mgic_catalog_product_entity`.`type_id` AS `type_id`,
  `mgic_cataloginventory_stock_item`.`qty` AS `qty`,
    MAX(Case WHEN `mgic_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 97 THEN `mgic_catalog_product_entity_int`.`value` END) AS status,
     MAX(Case WHEN `mgic_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 168 THEN `mgic_catalog_product_entity_int`.`value` END) AS range_status
FROM (((`mgic_eav_attribute`
  join `mgic_catalog_product_entity_int` on ((`mgic_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = `mgic_catalog_product_entity_int`.`attribute_id`)))
  join `mgic_catalog_product_entity` on ((`mgic_catalog_product_entity_int`.`entity_id` = `mgic_catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`)))
  join `mgic_cataloginventory_stock_item` on ((`mgic_catalog_product_entity_int`.`entity_id` = `mgic_cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id`)))
  WHERE `mgic_catalog_product_entity`.`type_id` = 'simple' AND `mgic_cataloginventory_stock_item`.`qty` = 0
GROUP BY `mgic_catalog_product_entity`.`sku`
HAVING  status = 1 and range_status = 96;
```

I am now trying to amend this to an update instruction to set the 'status' (attribute_id = 97) to disabled (id = 2) for the results list of the below query.

```
 update mgic_eav_attribute ea join 
  mgic_catalog_product_entity_int cpei on ea.attribute_id = cpei.attribute_id join
  mgic_catalog_product_entity cpe  on cpei.entity_id = cpe.entity_id join
  mgic_cataloginventory_stock_item cisi  on cpei.entity_id = cisi.product_id
  set cpei.value = 2
  WHERE cpe.type_id = 'simple' AND ((ea.attribute_code = 'status') and
  (cpei.value = 1)) AND cisi.qty = 0 AND EXISTS(
   SELECT
  cpe.sku,
  cpe.type_id,
  cisi.qty,
    MAX(Case WHEN ea.attribute_id = 97 THEN cpei.value END) AS status,
     MAX(Case WHEN ea.attribute_id = 168 THEN cpei.value END) AS range_status
FROM (((`mgic_eav_attribute`
  join `mgic_catalog_product_entity_int` on ((`mgic_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = `mgic_catalog_product_entity_int`.`attribute_id`)))
  join `mgic_catalog_product_entity` on ((`mgic_catalog_product_entity_int`.`entity_id` = `mgic_catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`)))
  join `mgic_cataloginventory_stock_item` on ((`mgic_catalog_product_entity_int`.`entity_id` = `mgic_cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id`)))
  WHERE `mgic_catalog_product_entity`.`type_id` = 'simple' AND `mgic_cataloginventory_stock_item`.`qty` = 0
GROUP BY cpei.entity_id
HAVING  status = 1 and range_status = 96);
```

The above query just seems to hang and doesn't execute.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic make it more likely that you'll get an answer.  You should also tag with a *database* -- which is presumably MySQL.

Comment: Right, so the only thing I missed there was Sample Data....?  I feel I explained the logic, even showing how I achieved the desired results.  Then explained what I wanted to achieve next, and how I'd gone about trying that.  I was looking for some help, not yet another blast from the almighty Gordon Linoff.